# excecute jQuery when arriving from certain links

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, hide, show

I have 5 images (person headshot photos). I am using the following jQuery to show and hide corresponding divs (to reveal information about each person) upon clicking on each image.

```
     $('.personDiv').hide();
     $('.listPerson').click(function(){
          $('.personDiv').hide();
          $('#person'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
          $('.listPerson').css('opacity', 0.6);
          $(this).css('opacity', 1);
     });
```

I would like particular images to be selected (and the corresponding div to be already shown) when arriving from certain links on other pages in the same way a href="example.html#anchor" links the user to a specific location of the linked page. How can I accomplish this with my scenario?'

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know how to accomplish something like that would be to use query string variables in your links from other pages then parse them with javascript on DOM ready and store the result in a variable which you would then use as the selector.

So if you had a URL like this:www.myurl.com?person=frank

```
$(function() {
  var params = {};
  var ps = window.location.search.split(/\?|&/);
  for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
        if (ps[i]) {
              var p = ps[i].split(/=/);
              params[p[0]] = p[1];
        }
  }
  var personToShow = params.person;
  $('#'+personToShow).show();
});
```

So something like this would essentially show whatever element has an ID of Frank on DOM ready.

Comment: Wow you're clever. Thanks so much for this. I'll try it out now.